# Preferences from for MEF plugin

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins, .net-4.0, mef, preferences

I make my application with VS2010 and .NET 4 with MEF for plugin framework. I see few examples in Google, for example [this](http://ctlabs.blogspot.ru/2009/10/mef-in-net-40visual-studio-2010-simple.html), it's good.

1. I want to call preferences form from each plugin when user select plugin from list.
2. My plugins may return various variable of unknown type (for main program). For example, next timer start time, processed data count, errors descriptions...

How to implement this feature?

Comment: 1. is "preferences form" a global form or unique to each plugin?

Comment: "Preferences form" unique to each plugin

Comment: your problem definition is inadequate; please explain it better.